# How would you know the voltage of a motor with no label?

Tags: voltage, motor

[image]

I found a motor.

Unfortunately the label has been removed.

How would I know what voltage it operates on?

- It has 2 wires.
- It has an attached square thing on it.
- It's either 12 volts, 110 volts, or 220 volts, because that is the only voltage we have in the factory.

Comment: How would you know it works? How would you know that it doesn't develop a fault when hot? How can you tell it isn't a fire risk? How much do you value your time and property? Buy a new one or one that is reconditioned by a pro.

Comment: At 6 uF it's a run capacitor, so single phase AC. 12V DC will probably cause damage. At 250V rating, the motor is most likely a 110V motor (start and run capacitors are usually 400V rated in 230V-land). The use of wire nuts suggests it's American, again suggesting 110V. Ditto black and white for the run winding.

Answer (score 4):

The motor has three connections, which argues for it being an AC motor.

The capacitor (the square thing) is connected to one side of the supply wires and to the motor.  It is either a start or a run capacitor.

The voltage rating on the capacitor is 250VAC.  That could mean the motor is for 230VAC, or 120VAC.  The capacitor would be overrated if 120VAC, or just appropriately rated for 230VAC (although I'd expect the capacitor to be rated for higher voltage if the motor were meant for 230VAC.)

---

You could try it first on 120VAC.  If it runs well, done.  If it runs poorly, the capacitor may be bad, or the motor may be intended for 230VAC, or the motor may be bad.  Or, maybe I'm wrong and it is a 12VDC motor and it'll blow up if connected to 120VAC.

Are you ready to experiment, and maybe extinguish a fire if things go bad?

Maybe you'd rather "find" a new motor from a store somewhere that can sell you a known good motor with specifications and a wiring diagram.

Comment: You are probably right. I think it is either 110v or 220v . how can I check if the capacitor is still good? what do you mean by if it runs poorly?  strange noise? heats up quickly?

Comment: Runs slow, doesn't start turning quickly when you turn it on, gets hot, has no power, etc.

Comment: noted with thanks, JRE.

Answer (score 0):

The "attached square thing", if I have read the writing on it correctly, is a 6 μF, 250 V capacitor, with the additional marking of "AC 50/60 Hz", all of which at least hints at the motor's voltage. No guarantees, though.

If you are certain about the possible voltages, you could test the motor with 12 V, see what happens, and if nothing much happens, test it with 110 V, and, again, see what happens.

Note that some 220 V motors will pull twice the current when used at 110 V and overheat. For a short test without mechanical load you should be fine, but don't use it in a real application until you have figured out what voltage it should be run at.

All this with the usual safety precautions, of course: it may be broken, it may short, it may set something on fire, who knows, so be careful, or just leave it and don't use it.

Comment: you are right. the capacitor is 6 uf +- 8%, 250 volts ac. 50/60hz. If i were to run it on 110 volts but in reality the motor was supposed to work on 220volts, would it damage the motor if I were to use it on 110 volts instead of 220volts?

Comment: It depends on the type of motor, which is unknown. Some 220V motors will pull twice the current when used at 110V and overheat. For a short test without mechanical load you should be fine, but don't use it in a real application until you have figured out what voltage is should be run at. At least check if it runs OK and doesn't overheat.

Comment: noted with thanks. will try it out. if it works then fine if not I'll just have to buy a new motor.

Comment: had the motor opened to check the condition first before plugging it to 12v, 110v, and then 220v.  it is like a small gear motor. replaced the dried up grease. extremely slow in 110 v. at 220volts, the speed is still slow but better. Problem is, after just a few minutes, you can feel that the body is a little warm. Dont know if it will get hot if I put on some load.